# Static pages in Orchard - how to implement them

Tags: orchardcms

I have several pages with static data, like About Us etc... Basically there's nothing dynamic about this pages... And my question is: how to implement these pages? I know I could add Pages to Pages list, and then copy/paste markup to body. But for me it would be more convienient to use MVC approach, where controller simply returns a:

```
return View();
```

from the action, and I have all my markup in cshtml file. Is it possible? If so, is it correct approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's possible. You just have to return a Shape with your custom content in an action marked as Themed. But I don't think that this is the correct approach. Why not just add pages? You could put HTML in the body section or even attach a custom part with the html (if you don't want to use a body part)

Comment: Well for instance I prefer to work with the markup in Web Matrix / Visual Studio than using TinyMCE. I loose flexibility of changing the content with Orchard Admin panel, but that's not the issue in my case. Could you provide a link / resource that describes this solution?

Comment: http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Building-a-hello-world-module but I really don't see how that's more flexible or more convenient.